# Unexpected type safety violation

Tags: java, casting

In the following code, a dowcast to an apparently incompatible type passes compilation:

```
public class Item {
  List<Item> items() { return asList(new Item()); }
  Item m = (Item) items();
}
```

`Item` and `List<Item>` are disparate types so the cast can never succeed. Why did the compiler allow this?

Comment: asList - just like that?

Comment: @laune `import static java.util.Arrays.asList;` I suppose...

Comment: also, isn't line 3 contained in a method or instance initializer?

Comment: `Item m` is an instance variable, initialized in place.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I missed that :(

Comment: `Item m = (Item) new Object();` compiles too...

Comment: @wha'eve' The static type of `new Object()` is `Object` and `Item` is an `Object`. This satisfies the rules for downcasts.

Comment: For completeness, this also compiles in Java 7.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A `List<Item>` could very well be an Item. See for example:

```
public class Foo extends Item implements List<Item> {
    // implement required methods
}
```

A cast tells the compiler: "I know you can't be sure that this is a object of type Item, but I know better than you, so please compile". The compiler will only refuse to compile that if it's impossible for the returned object to be an instance of Item (like, for example, `Integer` can't ever be a `String`)

At runtime, the type of the actual object returned by the method will be checked, and if it's not actually an object of type Item, you'll get a ClassCastException.

Comment: So basically it compiles because you could extend Item and make a subclass implement List<Item>. If you make Item final it no longer compiles.

Comment: Integer and String are final classes ;)

Comment: @pbabcdefp Exactly, that's what I noticed---the same doesn't work with, say, `String`.

Comment: @EugeneStepanenkov `Integer` and `String` are *classes*, that's all you need to know: a subclass of `Integer` can never become a `String`, be they final or not.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik then what exactly prevents you from doing `class Foo extends Integer implements String`? Integer and String being final seems to be crucial to the argument that this cannot happen.

Comment: @Martijn `String` being a class prevents me from it, whether final or not.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ah, you mean being a class in contrast to being an interface. That makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 17):

The relevant specification entry [can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1).  Let S be the source, and T the target; in this case, the source is the interface, and the target is a non-final type.

> If S is an interface type:
>
> - If T is an array type, then S must be the type `java.io.Serializable` or `Cloneable` (the only interfaces implemented by arrays), or a
>     compile-time error occurs.
> - If T is a type that is not final (§8.1.1), then if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are
>     provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and
>     Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.
>
>   Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (because even if
>     T does not implement S, a subclass of T might).

It took a few readings to get this straight, but let's start from the top.

- The target is not an array, so this rule doesn't apply.
- Our target does not have a parameterized type associated with it, so this rule would not apply.
- This means that the cast will always be legal at compile time, for the reason illustrated by JB Nizet:  our target class may not implement the source, but a subclass *might*.

This also means that it won't work if we cast to a final class that doesn't implement the interface, per this snippet:

> **If S is not a parameterized type or a raw type, then T must implement S, or a compile-time error occurs.**