# Java: Casting MyClass to List<MyClass>

Tags: java, casting

Why is it possible to cast `MyClass` object to `List<MyClass>` without compilation error (just having 'unchecked' warning), despite `MyClass` isn't implementing List interface, and at the same time isn't possible to cast, for example, `String` class the same way.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post some code demonstrating this? I'm not a Java specialist, but are you saying this as a general statement about **all** classes, or just `MyClass`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747562/unexpected-type-safety-violation

Comment: @WaiHaLee,
as it turned out after _rgettman_'s answer , it's about non-final classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will create a compiler error if the cast is completely impossible.  But when you cast to an interface (and your original class isn't `final`), it is possible for this cast to succeed.

It is possible, even though it may not exist, for a class you haven't written yet to subclass `MyClass` and implement `List`, even if that makes no sense to us.

Because of that possibility, the compiler must allow that cast.  But without such a subclass, this will still result in a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

The [JLS, Section 5.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1), states when casting `S` to `T`:

> - If T is an interface type:
>
>   - If S is not a final class (§8.1.1), then, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.
>
>     Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (**because even if S does not implement T, a subclass of S might**).
>   - If S is a final class (§8.1.1), then S must implement T, or a compile-time error occurs.

(bold emphasis mine)

Comment: oh, how can i forget about subclasses (-_-) thank you